# How do I connect to specific BLE device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using the [SimpleControls](https://github.com/RedBearLab/Android/tree/master/Examples/Android%20Studio%20Examples/SimpleControls/%22SimpleControls%22) application from redbearlabs and modifying it to my personal use.

The main layout looks like this, and the way to find and connect to a BLE device is by clicking the connect button, which scans and connects automatically to the device(s?) found.

**Problem:**
The app could pretty much connect to any BLE device it detects so I was wondering if its possible to specify the MAC address of the BLE device I have, in such a way that the logic is something like this:

```
if (address == "BB:EE:7A:89:B3:19")
{
    //connect
}
```

**Device I'm trying to connect to:** redbearlabs BLE Nano

Here's the **SimpleControls code** that contains the connection functions:

```
private Button connectBtn = null;
private TextView rssiValue = null;
//private TextView AnalogInValue = null;
private ToggleButton digitalOutBtn1, digitalOutBtn2, digitalOutBtn3;


private BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristicTx = null;
private RBLService mBluetoothLeService;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothDevice mDevice = null;
private String mDeviceAddress;

private boolean flag = true;
private boolean connState = false;
private boolean scanFlag = false;

private byte[] data = new byte[3];
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 2000;

final private static char[] hexArray = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
        '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName,
            IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLeService = ((RBLService.LocalBinder) service)
                .getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }
};

private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (RBLService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disconnected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setButtonDisable();
        } else if (RBLService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED
                .equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to BLE Nano",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            getGattService(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattService());
        } else if (RBLService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            data = intent.getByteArrayExtra(RBLService.EXTRA_DATA);

            //readAnalogInValue(data);
        } else if (RBLService.ACTION_GATT_RSSI.equals(action)) {
            displayData(intent.getStringExtra(RBLService.EXTRA_DATA));
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);

    rssiValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rssiValue);

    //AnalogInValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AIText);

    digitalOutBtn2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.digitalOutBtn2);

    connectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (scanFlag == false) {
                scanLeDevice();

                Timer mTimer = new Timer();
                mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mDevice != null) {
                            mDeviceAddress = mDevice.getAddress();
                            mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
                            scanFlag = true;
                        } else {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast toast = Toast
                                            .makeText(
                                                    SimpleControls.this,
                                                    "Couldn't search Ble Shield device!",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    toast.setGravity(0, 0, Gravity.CENTER);
                                    toast.show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            }

            System.out.println(connState);
            if (connState == false) {
                mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
            } else {
                mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
                mBluetoothLeService.close();
                setButtonDisable();
            }
        }
    });

    digitalOutBtn1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.digitalOutBtn1);
    digitalOutBtn1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            byte buf[] = new byte[] { (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };

            if (isChecked == true)
                buf[1] = 0x01; //turn on
            else
                buf[1] = 0x00; //turn off

            characteristicTx.setValue(buf);
            mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristicTx);
        }
    });

    digitalOutBtn3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.digitalOutBtn3);
    digitalOutBtn3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[] { (byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };

            if (isChecked == true)
                buf[1] = 0x01;
            else
                buf[1] = 0x00;

            characteristicTx.setValue(buf);
            mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristicTx);
        }
    });

    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ble not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        finish();
    }

    final BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ble not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(SimpleControls.this,
            RBLService.class);
    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
}

private void displayData(String data) {
    if (data != null) {
        rssiValue.setText(data);
    }
}

private void setButtonEnable() {
    flag = true;
    connState = true;

    digitalOutBtn1.setEnabled(flag);
    digitalOutBtn3.setEnabled(flag);
    connectBtn.setText("Disconnect");
}

private void setButtonDisable() {
    flag = false;
    connState = false;

    digitalOutBtn1.setEnabled(flag);
    digitalOutBtn3.setEnabled(flag);
    connectBtn.setText("Connect");
}

private void startReadRssi() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            while (flag) {
                mBluetoothLeService.readRssi();
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }.start();
}

private void getGattService(BluetoothGattService gattService) {
    if (gattService == null)
        return;

    setButtonEnable();
    startReadRssi();

    characteristicTx = gattService
            .getCharacteristic(RBLService.UUID_BLE_SHIELD_TX);

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristicRx = gattService
            .getCharacteristic(RBLService.UUID_BLE_SHIELD_RX);
    mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristicRx,
            true);
    mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristicRx);
}

private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

    intentFilter.addAction(RBLService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(RBLService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(RBLService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
    intentFilter.addAction(RBLService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
    intentFilter.addAction(RBLService.ACTION_GATT_RSSI);

    return intentFilter;
}

private void scanLeDevice() {
    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(SCAN_PERIOD);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }.start();
}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi,
            final byte[] scanRecord) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                byte[] serviceUuidBytes = new byte[16];
                String serviceUuid = "";
                for (int i = 30, j = 0; i >= 15; i--, j++) {
                    serviceUuidBytes[j] = scanRecord[i];
                }
                serviceUuid = bytesToHex(serviceUuidBytes);
                if (stringToUuidString(serviceUuid).equals(
                        RBLGattAttributes.BLE_SHIELD_SERVICE
                                .toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH))) {
                    mDevice = device;
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

private String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    int v;
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}

private String stringToUuidString(String uuid) {
    StringBuffer newString = new StringBuffer();
    newString.append(uuid.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH).substring(0, 8));
    newString.append("-");
    newString.append(uuid.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH).substring(8, 12));
    newString.append("-");
    newString.append(uuid.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH).substring(12, 16));
    newString.append("-");
    newString.append(uuid.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH).substring(16, 20));
    newString.append("-");
    newString.append(uuid.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH).substring(20, 32));

    return newString.toString();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    flag = false;

    unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mServiceConnection != null)
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I'm not sure how I can achieve what I want within this code. The digitalOutBtn are the buttons used to control the lights using the BLE device.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the LeScanCallback you can get the mac address from the BluetoothDevice object, use that to check if it is the device you are looking for. If it is not your device don't run the runnable.